# How To Save a File Generated by Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Tags: asp.net, excel

I am generating an excel file with Microsoft Interop.Excel. I need you to have the option to choose the save location. I am doing in ASP.NET C #.

Here is what I have so far:

```
Application excel = new Application(); 
Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet); 
Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)wb.Worksheets.get_Item(1); 
ws.Name = "Nome da Pasta"; 
ws.Cells[1, 1] = "POÇO:"; 
ws.Cells[2, 1] = "CAMPO:"; 
ws.Cells[3, 1] = "PERIODO:"; 
ws.Cells[5, 1] = "DATA HORA (M/D/Y)";
ws.Cells[5, 2] = "PRESSÃO DO POÇO (PSI)"; 
ws.Cells[5, 3] = "RPM DO POÇO"; 
ws.Columns.AutoFit(); 
excel.Quit();
```

Comment: Is this what you mean? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel._workbook.saveas?view=excel-pia

Comment: Application excel = new Application();
            Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
            Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)wb.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

            ws.Name = "Nome da Pasta";

            ws.Cells[1, 1] = "POÇO:";
            ws.Cells[2, 1] = "CAMPO:";
            ws.Cells[3, 1] = "PERIODO:";
            ws.Cells[5, 1] = "DATA HORA (M/D/Y)";
            ws.Cells[5, 2] = "PRESSÃO DO POÇO (PSI)";
            ws.Cells[5, 3] = "RPM DO POÇO";
            ws.Columns.AutoFit(); excel.Quit();

Comment: How to implement with the code above?

Comment: You mentioned ASP.NET.  Are you trying to save it on your server/network, or download it to a web/intranet user (web client)?

Comment: web/intranet user (web client)

Comment: help............

Answer (score 0):

In your code example, change it like this:

```
try {
   Application excel = new Application(); 
   Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Add       (XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet); 
   Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)wb.Worksheets.get_Item(1); 
   ws.Name = "Nome da Pasta"; 
   ws.Cells[1, 1] = "POÇO:"; 
   ws.Cells[2, 1] = "CAMPO:"; 
   ws.Cells[3, 1] = "PERIODO:"; 
   ws.Cells[5, 1] = "DATA HORA (M/D/Y)";
   ws.Cells[5, 2] = "PRESSÃO DO POÇO (PSI)"; 
   ws.Cells[5, 3] = "RPM DO POÇO"; 
   ws.Columns.AutoFit(); 
   //Save your file
   wb.SaveAs("c:\temp\SaveExample.xlsx");
   excel.Quit();
} catch (Exception ex) {
   //Log the exception, to NLog, or a file or something.
   //Otherwise, don't use a try/catch. Any error would get
   //logged in the Server's NT Event Log (under Application).
   //If this code doesn't work. Look there for the problem and
   //callstack.
}
```

One last thing: your save path must be writeable by the same account that IIS is using.  The easiest (for my example above) would be to make the `C:\Temp\` folder read/write for `Everyone`.